# what happens when converting char to string? (Java)

Tags: java, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I'm using String.valueOf  to convert char to string. But the return value seems not exactly same as a string of the same letter. Codes below:

```
    String myString = "s";
    char myChar = 's';//both string and char are assigned as letter 's'

    String stringFromChar = String.valueOf(myChar);

    if (myString == stringFromChar) {
        out.println("equal");
    } else {
        out.println("not equal");
    }
```

Every time it prints not equal. Please help, thanks! :)

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` compare the reference, not the actual value. You must use `equals` to compare the value.

Read this [article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) if you don't understand it's clear and simple.

Answer (score 3):

NEVER DO THIS AGAIN!!! PROMISE ME!!! =P

When comparing strings always, always, always use the equals method. See Below!

```
    String myString = "s";
    char myChar = 's';//both string and char are assigned as letter 's'

    String stringFromChar = String.valueOf(myChar);

    if (myString.equals(stringFromChar)) {
        System.out.println("equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Promised! And this seems different from C++ ...

Comment: The solution was so simple but I couldn't think of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> what happens when converting char to string?

Well, you are using the `String.valueOf(char)` method, whose javadoc does not say *how* it does the conversion.  But the behaviour you are seeing strongly suggests that the JVM you are using creates a new `String` object each time you call the method.

But you should depend on this happening.

The bottom line is that you *should always* use the `equals` method to compare strings.  Comparing strings with `==` will often give you false negatives ... depending on how the strings were created / obtained.  You've just been bitten by that.  Learn.

Reference:

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)